# JBoss doesn't process JMS messages

Tags: jms

Although JBoss seem to receive the JMS messages (I can list them through jmx-console) it doesn't process them. They stayed queued forever. What might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a message consumer running to process the queue?

This could be something like a message driven bean, or another JMS client connecting to the queue.